# JavaScript - Converting time from 12h into 24h format

Tags: javascript, time

I tried many methods, but I always end up without solution. What I need is a javascript code which can convert time from `div.postedOn` from 12h to 24h format.

div.postedTime example:

```
<div class="postedOn"><img src="http://assets7.thatsite.com/images/forums/post/reply.gif?v3" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted on June 3, 2012 1:46 AM</div>
```

So, I need to convert '1:46 PM' to '01:46' without removing any contents from the `<div>`.

Comment: 24h? or add a leading 0? 1PM is 1300

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the time in its own element (such as a `span`), just to make it easier to grab that time without having perform regex (or any other string manipulation) to find it before then formatting/adjusting it.

Comment: A simple regex replace with a function in the callback would provide the basic functionality, but honestly, as you're editing a forum software, it'd be **much** easier if you'd just format the date correctly before echo'ing in the page/template. Or do you want to add user-specific personalization with JS? Even in this case, the server-side would be the way to go.

Comment: @Jo The text in the `<div>` actually says `1:46 AM`, so presumably that's what's intended to be 01:46.

Comment: @DavidThomas How would I do that? I'm a total beginner to javascript coding, so I'm not so experienced. And how would I perform a regex replace after that?

Comment: See [Kolink's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10874775/82548). Also, read about [RegExp at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Kolink, adding another regex solution...

```
var str = "Posted on June 3, 2012 2:00 PM";
var regex = /([01]?\d)(:\d{2}) (AM|PM)/g;
var match = regex.exec(str);
str.replace(regex, (+match[1] + (match[3]=='AM'? 0 : 12)) + match[2] + match[3]);
```

Comment: This one works! Thanks! I'd thumb up both of you, but I can't. My reputation is low.

Comment: Except this doesn't account for 12:00 AM and PM.

Answer (score 4):

If the format is always the same, then this will work fine:

```
out = in.replace(/(\d+):(\d+) ([AP])M/,function(m) {
    m[1] = m[1]%12;
    if( m[3] == "P") m[1] += 12;
    if( m[1] < 10) m[1] = "0"+m[1];
    return m[1]+":"+m[2];
});
```

Comment: It looks confusing to me. Can you explain in short how to use it?

Comment: Basically, it looks for an hour, minute and meridian. Then it turns `12` into `0` (because 12AM is midnight) and adds 12 if it's PM. Then if the hours are less than 10 it adds a leading zero, and finally returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure because i've not done javascript in a while, but you would do something like this.. 
(this is pseuedo btw)

```
if( timeString.contains("pm") ) {
hour += 12%24;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if that will work, but that is the basic idea none the less. i hope i helped.

Comment: `12%24` is always equal to 12, so basically you're just adding 12 hours. What if it's 12AM? By your logic, that would make it noon.

Comment: As i said , it was the basic idea on how to do it, so if it was 3pm then the new time would be 15 if it was 12 am, then the 12 would not be added it would stay at 1200 until it became 1 pm where it would then change to 1300

Comment: @Kolink 12AM wouldn't contain "pm" :) The only case where this code wouldn't work is between 12PM and 1PM

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "12:00 AM";
var regex = /([01]?\d)(:\d{2}) (a.m.|p.m.|AM|PM)/g;
var match = regex.exec(str);
var test;
if (match[1] == 12 && (match[3] == 'p.m.' || match[3] == 'PM')) {
    test = '12 h';
} else if (match[1] == 12 && (match[3] == 'a.m.' || match[3] == 'AM')) {
    test = '0 h';
} else {
    test = str.replace(regex, (+match[1] + (match[3]=='a.m.'? 0 : 12)) + ' h');
}
console.log(test);
```

Would this work, in regards to catching those pesky "12 AM" and "12 PM" situations?